# Why doesn't NuGet pack add files to tools directory?

Tags: nuget, nuget-package, nuget-spec

I have the following nuspec file:

```
<files>
    <file src="..\.BuildScripts\Tools\*.ps1" target="tools" />
    <file src="..\Build\Results\*.*" target="content" exclude="*.txt" />
</files>
```

when I run `NuGet pack project.nuspec`, the process completes without any errors, however the tools directory of the created package is empty. When I change the path of the first line to a non-existing path, I do get an error (`File not found`).

What is wrong with the NuSpec file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently NuGet does not like dots `.` in paths. Simply renaming `.BuildScripts` to `BuildScripts` solves the problem:

```
<file src="..\BuildScripts\Tools\*.ps1" target="tools" />
```

Lesson learned, the hard way!

Answer (score 0):

There is a `NoDefaultExcludes` command line option to `nuget pack` that overrides this behavior ([NuGet Pack Command Options](https://docs.nuget.org/consume/command-line-reference#pack-command-options))